# Raster brightness, contrast, saturation in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I'm trying to find a way to change these properties (especially contrast and brightnes) and I've found a `QgsBrightnessContrastFilter` class, but I can't fugure out how to apply it to my raster layer.

I think that can be done with:

```
contrastFilter = QgsBrightnessContrastFilter()
contrastFilter.setContrast(100)
```

But what now? How to set this filter to my layer?

Comment: If I need to assign to multiple layer, how can avoid the qgis crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After crawling through the source code I got this:

```
# get the raster layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# define the filter
contrastFilter = QgsBrightnessContrastFilter()
contrastFilter.setContrast(50) #For brightness use contrastFilter.setBrightness(50)

# assign filter to raster pipe
layer.pipe().set(contrastFilter)

# apply changes
layer.triggerRepaint()

# to set contrast back, change properties of assigned filter.
# DO NOT ASSIGN THIS OR ANOTHER QgsBrightnessContrastFilter AGAIN, QGIS WILL CRASH
contrastFilter.setContrast(0)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```